# C# datatype for storing strings in a table

Tags: c#

which is the best datatype for storing string in a table in sql server?

Comment: The best datatype would be `string`

Comment: A table? Are you talking about a database table, or some kind of 2-d array?

Answer (score 8):

In SQL Server:

- `VARCHAR(x)` for non-Unicode strings
- `NVARCHAR(x)` for Unicode strings

For extra long text (more than 4000 Unicode or 8000 non-Unicode characters):

- `VARCHAR(MAX)` for non-Unicode strings
- `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for Unicode strings

`TEXT` and `NTEXT` are deprecated with SQL Server 2005 and should *not* be used anymore (the NVARCHAR(MAX)/VARCHAR(MAX) also support all string functions, which is a big plus).

For short (less than 10 chars) and fixed elements, like two-character state abbreviations etc., use `CHAR(x) / NCHAR(x)` instead of VARCHAR. Be aware though: those fields are always padded to the defined length with spaces!

Comment: `TEXT` for extra-long strings? Also `VARCHAR` fields are hard on searches - it's good to use `CHAR` when possible.

Comment: @Jake: no way - SQL Server 2005 deprecates TEXT/NTEXT - use VARCHAR(MAX) / NVARCHAR(MAX) instead.